# Setting default values in app settings in web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my project I have user type table in which I stored only 2 ids

**UserType** Table

```
Usertype id Name
3 Customer User
5 Business User
```

I need to set that 2 ids in the web.config file in my MVC project. While coming in code we need to call that from web.config file. Is it possible to do

I hardcoded the value in the below code

```
public ActionResult Calendar(int id)
{

var cal = (from s
in db.tblUsers
where s.UserTypeId == 5 && s.UserID == id
select new Appt
{
FirstName = s.FirstName,
BusinessCategory = s.tblBusinessCategory.BusinessCategory,
BusinessName = s.tblBusinessCategory.BusinessName,
StartTime = s.WorkingHour.StartTime,
UserTypeID =5,
UserID = s.UserID
}).FirstOrDefault();
Session["BUId"] = id;
return View(cal);

}
```

in that usertype id we need the get the value from web.config.

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `<appSettings>` section in web.config as follows and read that value using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["usertypeid"]`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="usertypeid" value="5"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: @Nisha Please Mark this as useful answer for you